# Magento 2 - HTML on the tag Comment in the custom module

Tags: magento2, module, adminhtml

How to add html on the tag comment in my module like this image?

[image: html on the tag comment - magento2]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use **CDATA** tag like this code below:

> File: code/[Package]/[Module]/etc/adminhtml/system.xml

```
<field id="pattern" translate="label comment" type="text" sortOrder="3" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
    <label>Gift code pattern</label>       
    <comment><![CDATA[Generate gift codes for Gift Card products. For example:<br/><strong>[A.8] : 8 alpha<br/>[N.4] : 4 numeric<br/>[AN.6] : 6 alphanumeric<br/>GIFT-[A.4]-[AN.6] : GIFT-ADFA-12NF0O</strong>]]></comment>
</field>
```

Answer (score 1):

Also, if you need an html tag to be displayed as plain text in comment - replace `<` with `&lt;` and `>` with `&gt;`

E.g.:

```
<comment><![CDATA[Some comment with tag as plain text - &lt;rating&gt;4.3&lt;/rating&gt;]]></comment>
```

The above will be displayed as

```
Some comment with tag as plain text - <rating>4.3</rating>
```

Comment: Just to note that it doesn't work on `system.xml` files using: **magento2.2.2**

Answer (score 0):

I have used HTML in my code using `&lt;` and `&gt;` and it is working fine. No `<!CDATA>` required for this

Sample code:

```
<comment>
    &lt;strong&gt;Heading:&lt;/strong&gt; &lt;br&gt;
    Text line one here &lt;br&gt;
    Text line two here &lt;br&gt;
    Text line three here
</comment>
```